# Angular asynchronous calls

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

The problem appears to be related to the update times of the `controlSelected` and `isAssessmentDataLoading` variables. The `updateQuestions()` method is called within the `ngOnInit()` method, which is called when the component is first created.

However, the `assessmentData.securityControl` variable is not populated until the `setAssessmentData()` method completes, which happens asynchronously.

As a result, the `updateQuestions()` method is called before the `assessmentData.securityControl` variable has been updated, which causes the `controlSelected` variable to remain `true` even if a valid security control is available. How do I solve this?

I would like to try to adapt `updateQuestions()` to be called when assessment has been retrieved.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.setAssessmentData(this.navigationService.getSavedID());

  this.isControlSecurityComplete = this.navigationService.getControlSecurityComplete();

  if (this.isControlSecurityComplete) {
    this.dataService.selectedSecurity$.subscribe((value) => {
      this.selectedSecurity = value;
    });
    this.questions.forEach(question => {
      question.selectedOption = null;
    });
  }
}

setAssessmentData(assessmentID: string) {
  this.assessmentService.getAssessmentById(assessmentID).subscribe(
    (assessment) => {
      this.assessmentData.nomeAssessment = assessment['nomeAssessment'];
      this.assessmentData.dataAssessment = assessment['dataAssessment'];
      this.assessmentData.nomeStruttura = assessment['nomeStruttura'];
      this.assessmentData.nomeCittaOSito = assessment['nomeCittaOSito'];
      this.assessmentData.statoProvinciaRegione = assessment['statoProvinciaRegione'];
      this.assessmentData.contatti.nome = assessment['contatti'] ? .nome;
      this.assessmentData.contatti.ruolo = assessment['contatti'] ? .ruolo;
      this.assessmentData.contatti.email = assessment['contatti'] ? .email;
      this.assessmentData.selectedCategory = assessment['selectedCategory'];
      this.assessmentData.securityLevel = assessment['securityLevel'];
      this.assessmentData.securityControl = assessment['securityControl'];
      this.assessmentData.domande = assessment['domande'];
      this.assessmentData.rispostaChatGPT = assessment['rispostaChatGPT'];

      if (this.assessmentData.securityControl == '') {
        this.controlSelected = true;
      } else {
        this.updateQuestions(this.assessmentData.securityControl);
        this.controlSelected = false;
      }
    },
    (error) => {
      this.isAssessmentDataLoading = false;
      console.error('Errore nel recupero dell\'assessment', error);
    }
  );
}

updateQuestions(controlName: string) {
  this.dataService.getJsonDataNew(controlName).subscribe((data) => {
    if (data && data.fileDocument && Array.isArray(data.fileDocument.fileData)) {
      this.questions = data.fileDocument.fileData.filter((item: any) => item.Security <= this.selectedSecurity);
    } else {
      this.questions = [];
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: from what I see here, it looks like updateQuestions is called after you get the assessment data.  (the other calls in ngOnInit are not waiting though).  You can chain those inside of it, just like you did for updateQuestions if they rely on data you are receiving through the subscription...)

Answer (score 0):

First things first, try not to get tangled up in nested subscribe() calls – it's kind of a no-go, known as an anti-pattern. The problem here is that you lose control over how stuff gets emitted, and you might end up with some values left hanging.

So, when you're diving into the `getAssessmentById` subscription and tossing in a `subscribe()` for `dataService.getJsonDataNew()`, you're unwittingly stumbling into that anti-pattern territory. This could very well be the root of the issues you're facing – handling subscriptions in a not-so-friendly way.

A better approach would be to refactor your code and use RxJS operators. [SwitchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) is a good choice for updating your subscriptions in a more organised way.

I updated the code below:

```java
setAssessmentData(assessmentID: string) {
    this.assessmentService.getAssessmentById(assessmentID).pipe(
      filter(Boolean), // to avoid null values
      switchMap((assessment) => { // switchMap will intrerupt inner emissions if a new value is emitted by the outer observable, it you want other behavior, like waiting for inner observable to finish before taking a new emission, search about higher-order mapping operators.
        this.mapAssessmentData(assessment);
  
        if (this.assessmentData.securityControl) {
          this.controlSelected = false;
          return this.dataService.getJsonDateNew(this.assessmentData.securityControl);
        } else {
          this.controlSelected = true;
          return of(false);
        }
      })
    ).subscribe(
      (val) => {
        if (val) {
          if (val.fileDocument && Array.isArray(val.fileDocument.fileData)) {
            this.questions = val.fileDocument.fileData.filter((item: any) => item.Security <= this.selectedSecurity);
          } else {
            this.questions = [];
          }
        }
      },
      (err) => this.handleError(err) // Handle errors in a separate function
    );
  }
  
  handleError(error: any) {
    // Add your error handling logic here
    console.error('Error:', error);
  }

function mapAssessmentData(assessment: any) {
    this.assessmentData.nomeAssessment = assessment['nomeAssessment'];
    this.assessmentData.dataAssessment = assessment['dataAssessment'];
    this.assessmentData.nomeStruttura = assessment['nomeStruttura'];
    this.assessmentData.nomeCittaOSito = assessment['nomeCittaOSito'];
    this.assessmentData.statoProvinciaRegione = assessment['statoProvinciaRegione'];
    this.assessmentData.contatti.nome = assessment['contatti'] ? .nome : ;
    this.assessmentData.contatti.ruolo = assessment['contatti'] ? .ruolo : ;
    this.assessmentData.contatti.email = assessment['contatti'] ? .email : ;
    this.assessmentData.selectedCategory = assessment['selectedCategory'];
    this.assessmentData.securityLevel = assessment['securityLevel'];
    this.assessmentData.securityControl = assessment['securityControl'];
    this.assessmentData.domande = assessment['domande'];
    this.assessmentData.rispostaChatGPT = assessment['rispostaChatGPT'];
}
```

Note: It’s not very clear for me if you have some dependencies with the other subscriptions. If this is the case you might want to have a look over [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest) from RxJs or some other combining operator depending on your needs.

I hope this helps you

Happy coding!

Comment: I was trying to follow your solution but it gives me an error at `this.assessmentData.contacts.name = assessment['contatti'] ? .nome: ;` I also tried to remove the : , but nothing, I don't know how to solve it

Comment: Yes, remove ':' and please provide the error.

Comment: I solved this syntax problem, but still the problem is not solved. ControlSelected is not updated before the call.